# How to enable a field in contact form 7 when selecting a particular value in droplist

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

> I have created a contact form in my wordpress website using the plugin
>   contact form7. Now I want to enable a field in the contact form only
>   when the user select a particular value in dropdown list [in the same
>   form].
>
> Example: Show the form upload field when the user select the option
>   **image** in the dropdown list

Please help me to do it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do using JQuery  hide()/show()

Put this jQuery  code in footer

> **#fileimage** Change this id to your form **upload field** id
>
> **#selectid** Change this id to your form  select field id

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap #fileimage").hide();
    jQuery("#selectid").change(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val()=="image")
        {
            jQuery(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap #fileimage").show();
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap #fileimage").hide();
        }
        
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The field you want to open by choose the option from drop down list.You need to create hidden fields below your drop down list and you need to write jQuery according to your requirement which field you want to show on selected option.